# Как изменить поле типа image в Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Мне нужно сделать апдейт параметров alt и title в картинки во время сохранения.Чтобы не генерировать эти параметры вручную

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function MODULE_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'press_release') {
    $title = $node->getTitle();

    $images = $node->get('field_image')->getValue();
    $first_image = reset($images);
    $first_image['alt'] = $title;
    $first_image['title'] = $title;

    $node->field_image->setValue($first_image);
  }
}
```

Более детально можно глянуть здесь
[Programmatically attach files to a node in Drupal 8](http://realityloop.com/blog/2015/10/08/programmatically-attach-files-node-drupal-8)